# Error opening a class in Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) inside a maven module

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven project containing several modules. This is part of the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tdk.booking.codemap</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdkmap-maven-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tdk.booking.tdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tdks</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0-RC1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>tdk Services</name>
    <description>Document, File and Meeting Services</description>

    <modules>
        <module>tdk-services</module>
        <module>tdk-audit</module>
        <module>tdk-procedure</module>
        <module>tdk-persistence-model</module>
        <module>tdk-common</module>
        <module>tdk-war</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Quartz framework -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>${quartz.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- LOG4J2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

     .....

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I am on Eclipse and I try to open a class using **F3** that is inside of one of the modules, like `tdk-services`, I got the error

```
Problems opening an editor.
Reason:
tdk-services does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import all the modules as independent projects: *File - Import - Existing Project into Workspace* and select the child project. Navigate using *F3* or *Ctrl - click*.